# If I center my kernel does it no longer remain positive semidefinite?? If so why is it being used in algorithms like kernel pca?

Tags: pca, svm, kernel-trick, ridge-regression

If I center my kernel then can it still be used in operations where a positive semi-definite kernel is required such as SVM and ridge regression?

I am centering my kernel as follows:
$$K_c(\mathbf{t}_i, \mathbf{x}_j ) = K(\mathbf{t}_i, \mathbf{x}_j ) − κ(\mathbf{t}_i)\mathbf{1}^T_j − \mathbf{1}_iκ(\mathbf{x}_j)^T + k\mathbf{1}_i\mathbf{1}_j^T$$

Comment: Welcome  to the site. Why and how are you "centering a kernel"? An example might help to clarify.

Comment: I am centering the kernel gram matrix based on the following article: https://www.ics.uci.edu/~welling/classnotes/papers_class/Kernel-PCA.pdf

Comment: I am centering my kernel so that I can achieve normalization of features in the RKHS as well. It is stated in ics.uci.edu/~welling/classnotes/papers_class/Kernel-PCA.pdf.